# Turn header menu/navbar's texts turn into icons for small viewports (rails 4/bootstrap3)

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap 3 on a Rails 4 app.

I have a "normal" fixed navbar on the page headers. For the moment, when the viewport decreases (small device), all menu titles disappear and go into the "three bars" icon like here: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/ (try on a small screen/viewport).

Is it possible with bootstrap 3 to NOT make all menu titles go into this three bar icon, but to replace all texts **by very small icons** (for example Help would be replaced by a " ? "icon) so that there is enough space for all of them, when the viewport is very small.

Is there something already built-in inside Bootstrap allowing to do that ? or maybe some external libraries that play well with BS3?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That should not be to hard, and no need for a framework. You can use the [responsive utility classes](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities) provided by BS3. With those, you can hide the icons on big screen and show the labels, and the opposite when on small screen. Your `navbar` markup would look something like this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">
        <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-user visible-xs-inline-block'></i>
        <span class='hidden-xs'>Link</span>
      </a></li>
      <li><a href="#">
        <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-user visible-xs-inline-block'></i>
        <span class='hidden-xs'>Link</span>
      </a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

And a small line of css is required to prevent the `li` from being displayed as `block` on small screens. Something like this should do the trick:

```
.nav>li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

And an example to demonstrate: http://www.bootply.com/a17IsJ0Pop